# Cannot find module 'cylon'

Tags: node.js, cylon.js

I'm trying to move my bb-8(sphero) with cylon.js.
I installed node.js, cylon-ble module globally and made simple code to move my bb-8.

My environment is

- MacBook Pro Early 2015
- OS X El Capitan

The following error occurred while executing bb-8.js.

```
$ node bb-8.js 
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'cylon'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tomo/NodeJS/bb-8/bb-8.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
```

bb-8.js

```
var Cylon = require('cylon');

Cylon.robot({
  connections: {
    bluetooth: { adaptor: 'central', uuid: 'e6677e25df494211864219ce120ca051', module: 'cylon-ble'}
  },

  devices: {
    bb8: { driver: 'bb8', module: 'cylon-sphero-ble'}
  },

  work: function(my) {
    my.bb8.color(0x00FFFF);

    after(500, function() {
      my.bb8.color(0xFF0000);
    });

    after(1000, function() {
      my.bb8.roll(60, 0);
    });

    after(2000, function() {
      my.bb8.roll(60, 180);
    });

    after(3000, function() {
      my.bb8.stop();
    });
  }
}).start();
```

I checked modules, seems ok.

```
$ npm ls
/Users/tomo/NodeJS/bb-8
└── (empty)


$ npm ls -g | grep cylon
├─┬ cylon-ble@0.10.1
│ ├── cylon@1.2.0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install cylon module locally since is a dependency of your proyect or set NODE_PATH env variable.

```
$ cd /Users/tomo/NodeJS/bb-8    
$ npm install cylon
```

It's recommended use

```
$ npm init
$ npm install --save cylon
```

In order to write that dependency in your package.json for future installations.

Take a look [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) for a better explanation about how Node.js search for modules in your projects.